# Excess '4' occurs in the end of number when summing negative floats

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
In: -0.01 + (-0.02) + (-0.4) + (-0.05)
Out: -0.48000000000000004
```

Instead of -0.48

Why does it happen so?
And how to avoid such situations?

Comment: You have encoutered the downsides of float arithemtic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken